# Batch processing with Vert.x

Tags: vert.x

Is there a way to do a typical batch processing with Vert.x - like providing a file or DB query as input and let each record be processed by a vertice in non-blocking way.

In examples of Vertice, a server is defined in startup. And even though multiple vertices are deployed, server is created only onece. Which means that Vert.x engine does have a build in concept of a server and knows how to send incomming requests to each vertice for processing.

Same happens with Event Bus as well.

But is there a way to define a vertice with a handler for processing data from a general stream - query, file, etc..

I am particularly interested in spreading data processing over cluster nodes.

One way I can think of, is execute a query a regular way and then publish data to event bus for processing. But that means that if I have to process few millions of records, I will run out of memory. Of course I could do paging, etc.. - but there is no coordination between retrieving and processing of data.

Thanks
Andrius

Comment: Could you clarify your use-case? Do want to send data via the event bus and consume in other verticles/Handlers? Or just have the data on the eventBus?

Comment: I have data in DB or in a file. I want to process it in multiple threads and over multiple cluster nodes. Solution does not need to involve event bus at all if it is not needed - tcp server does not publish data to a bus to process it - it simply calls a handler directly.

Comment: Tried processing them in worker threads?

Comment: You can run compute expensive tasks and all most of the load you have in worker verticle with worker threads. You can get some info from https://medium.com/@pvub/https-medium-com-pvub-vert-x-workers-6a8df9b2b9ee

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [JDBC Client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/#_legacy_jdbc_client_api), you can stream the query result:

(using vertx-rx-java2)

```java
JDBCClient client = ...;

JsonObject params = new JsonArray().add(dataCategory);
client.rxQueryStreamWithParams("SELECT * FROM data WHERE data.category = ?", params)
      .flatMapObservable(SQLRowStream::toObservable)
      .subscribe(
          (JsonArray row) -> vertx.eventBus().send("data.process", row)
      );
```

This way each row is send to the event bus. If you then have multiple verticle instances that each listen to this address, you spread the data processing to multiple threads.

If you are using [another SQL Client](https://vertx.io/docs/#databases) have a look at its documentation - Maybe is has a similar method.